# Where do I find the RpInitiatedLogoutResponse in the OpenidConnectPkce Class?

Tags: openid-connect, itfoxtec-identity-blazor

I have difficulty to find the object of `RpInitiatedLogoutResponse` in the line of 316 in the function of `LogoutCallBackAsync` in this class:
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.BlazorWebAssembly.OpenidConnect/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.BlazorWA.Oidc/OpenidConnectPkce.cs

Answer (score 1):

The [ITfoxtec Identity Blazor](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.BlazorWebAssembly.OpenidConnect) component is based on the [ITfoxtec Identity](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity) component where you find the [RpInitiatedLogoutResponse](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity/blob/master/src/Messages/RpInitiatedLogoutResponse.cs) class.